# How-to Get Best Performance With Large Amount Of Data In aspx page?

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I want to display 1000 rows and 80 rows in a GridView. I am little bit worried about the Performance of the application. If you know how to make it better performance ,please tell hw to do that in detailed way.

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Me.FillGrid()
        End If
    End Sub
```

'Filling The Grid

```
Private Sub FillGrid()


 Try
        Dim MyCompany As New Company
        Dim mydsCompanyDSource As DataSet

        mydsCompanyDSource = MyCompany.DisplayData()

        gvCompany.DataSource = mydsCompanyDSource
        gvCompany.DataBind()

    Catch ex As Exception
        CreatelogFile(ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Paging of the gridview is true . if Large amount of data will come , any performance problems will come ?

Comment: Profile your application and see if you run into issues? :)

Comment: Without paging your page could be very slow to load those 1000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

1000 rows is going to be heavy, anything over a 100 is a good candidate for [Paging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx) - only return 10 rows, for example, at a time.